# How should I send the username and a password to the server?

Tags: javascript, security, node.js, passwords

I'm building a game for which the players can create accounts, you know, the standard scheme. But, I'd like to depend solely on Javascript, both on the server side (Node.js) and on the client side.

My primary means of communication with the server is usually Socket.io, and I guess that sending the passwords in plaintext isn't a good idea - but I don't know why! I mean, can someone sniff the traffic or something? How does that happen exactly? And most importantly, what's the solution to this problem?

I know that I need to save passwords as hashes on the server-side.

Comment: anyone can sniff traffic. packets are sent through any public network...when routers get it and it's not for their network, they pass it on...but you can use a sniffer there to capture all traffic. normally, sniffing is more prevalent with wireless networks, because wireless transmissions can be intercepted much easier than wired...but that means the sniffer has to be in the vicinity of the wireless network. a popular technique is session hijacking - where sniffers find the session ID in HTTP requests (looking at cookies) and then all they have to do is set their cookie value to that to hijack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is [use HTTPS](http://silas.sewell.org/blog/2010/06/03/node-js-https-ssl-server-example/) by [creating your own SSL certificate](http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html).

Even GMail did not have an option to [use HTTPS all the time](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/07/making-security-easier.html) until 2008. I'm constantly amazed how much we still don't care about security.

Speaking of which, do salt your hashed passwords. Salting is easy... pick a word, any word. Append it to the password and hash that. (i.e. SHA1(password . mysalt)) A few people have had [some trouble with that recently](http://news.yahoo.com/linkedin-eharmony-passwords-leaked-online-025345760--finance.html). Adding a bit 'o salt will at least prevent an easy rainbow attack.

Comment: prepend - don't append. also the salt should be per user, don't "pick a word"

Comment: Please explain, @GoodPerson, why should I do these things?

Comment: even better, don't even roll your own, better use a standard key derivation function like scrypt.   The reason not to append has to with certain types of length extension attacks. the reason to choose a per user salt is to force the attacker to create a table per user (ie they won't be able to do prep work)

Comment: I suggest [bcrypt](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/) instead of hashing.

Comment: @elmigranto scrypt is a better KBPDF to use than bcrypt